# Laravel y AdminLTE (modificar un label)

Tags: php, laravel, adminlte

estoy probando Laravel con la plantilla AdminLTE, y tengo una cuestión que no se cómo se hace.
En la siguiente pantalla:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

quiero modificar el label de forma dinámica, que dependiendo de los datos que obtenga de mi BD ya definida (con todos los modelos pertinentes) muestre un número u otro.

El archivo html es el siguiente:

**index.blade.php**

```
@extends('adminlte::page')

@section('title', 'Pruebas')

@section('content_header')
    <h1>Dashboard</h1>
@stop

@section('content')
    <p>Welcome to this beautiful admin panel </p>
@stop

@section('css')
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/admin_custom.css">
@stop

@section('js')
    <script> console.log('Hi!'); </script>
@stop
```

Ese contenedor se encuentra en el archivo **admintle.php**, en una parte del código que es el siguiente:

```
'menu' => [
        ['header' => 'Expedientes'],
        [
            'text'        => 'Últimos expedientes',
            'url'         => 'admin/pages',
            'icon'        => 'far fa-fw fa-file',
            'label'       => 4,          <-- ESTO QUIERO QUE SE MODIFIQUE DINÁMICAMENTE
            'label_color' => 'success',
        ],




        // Navbar items:
        [
            'type'         => 'navbar-search',
            'text'         => 'search',
            'topnav_right' => true,
        ],
...
```

En resumen, quiero coger datos de mi BD mediante los modelos (un simple SELECT * FROM [tabla]) y modificar el label en base al número de resultados devueltos.

Gracias de antemano, un saludo.

Answer (score -1):

Este paso es para insertar un menú desde  EventServiceProvider
app\Providers\EventServiceProvider,
trabajo en laravel version 8

public function boot(){

```
    Event::listen(BuildingMenu::class, function (BuildingMenu $event){
        $conteo= Amigos::all()->count();
        $event->menu->add([
            'text' => 'Amigos', 
            'route' => 'admin.amigos.index', 
            'icon'=> 'far fa-fw fa-file',
            'label' =>  $conteo,
            'label_color' =>'success']);
    });


}
```

}

Comment: ajjaja, disculpa la costumbre. Solo debes agregar ese codigo en tu EventServiceProvider y generar la consulta al modelo que desees. siga los pasos mencionados anteriormente :) buen dia

Comment: Hola probe tu codigo me sale el siguiente error me podrias ayudar Undefined type 'App\Providers\BuildingMenu'.intelephense(1009)

Comment: edite la solución creo que se debe  cerrar y abrir llaves de la función boot()